Superset Oauth2 problem with redirect uri in http instead https:
I'm using a supserset installation in virtual enviroment, gunicorn, nginx and apache since most of my sites in my server use apache. I'm trying to use Oauth2 with EntraID but the redirect_uri returns in http instead desired https. Looking on internet I found that most of the time ENABLE_PROXY_FIX=True solves the problem but not in my case:
Nginx settings:
server {
    listen 9999;
    server_name domain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn_superset.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # Eliminamos esta línea porque Apache ya configura este encabezado
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}

Apache settings:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on

    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerName example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9999/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile 'DIRECTORY'
    SSLCertificateKeyFile 'DIRECTORY'
    Include 'DIRECTORY'

    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl "on"

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

Apache superset settings
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX=True

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'DATABE'

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {   'name':'Alephsub0-EntraID',
        'token_key':'access_token', # Name of the token in the response of access_token_url
        'icon':'fa-sign-in',   # Icon for the provider
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id':'ClienID',  # Client Id (Identify Superset application)
            'client_secret':'ClientSecret', # Secret for this Client Id (Identify Superset application)
            'server_metadata_url':'url/.well-known/openid-configuration',
            'client_kwargs':{
                'scope': 'User.Read'               # Scope for the Authorization
            },
        }
    }
]

# Will allow user self registration, allowing to create Flask users from Authorized User
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION=True

# The default user self registration role
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public"


SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='None'
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True

# Proxy fix configuration
PROXY_FIX_CONFIG = {
    'x_for': 1,
    'x_proto': 1,
    'x_host': 1,
    'x_port': 1,
    'x_prefix': 1
}

Any suggestion?
Use ENABLE_PROXY_FIX=True. Headers in apache and nginx
